# how to prevent select from table using cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, unique

I have cakephp site
it is for a company, who frequently submit forms from different branches
any many users from each branch doing data entry
I have to generate formID dynamically based on other table values
so before insertion, I do select from tbl1, tbl2, tbl3,tbl4 and concatenate them.
I am worried if at the same time another data entry operator submit form, then duplication of formID may cause
how can I confirm unique formID in my case.
------------edited-----------
I have to generate formID in the following format

```
project_code-sub_project_code-version_name-last_id+1   

ABCD01-WEBAPP-Beta-23
```

'project_code' is in 'projects' table
'sub_project_code' is in 'sub_projects' table
'version_name' is in 'versions' table
and
I have 'clients' table which has foreign keys referencing above tables
now on inserting 'clients' record
I am selecting 'project_code' from 'projects' table, 'sub_project_code' from 'sub_projects' table.....
and 'count(*)+1' from 'clients' table
now concatenate all these and insert into 'clients' table as 'formID'

Comment: What exactly is your "algorithm" to generate formID? What does tbl1 - tbl4 have to do with the form being submitted? _(If you need a unique identifier, have you looked at GUID/UUID's or auto-incrementing primary keys?)_

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the formID in the clients table you have a list of existing formIDs. After selecting the data to build the formID, but before inserting, check to see if the formID already exists. If not you can be certain that it is unique. If the formID already exists then you know not to insert it and you can return back the existing record id if needed.

Given this check, two people will not be able to insert the same formID as the first person will be successful but the second will have detected the existing formID.

Making the formID select to check for uniqueness will need to be done unless you come up with another way to compare.